# How Could I calculate Probability Of Probability Between 2 Price

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

In x Axis, I have 2 Price that have independent probability of occur.

1- First Price 50: Probability Of Price become Above that is is 40% and below that is 60%.

2- Second Price 110: Probability Of Price become Above that is is 20% and below that is 80%.

How Could I Calculate Probability of price these price toghether:

below 50, Between 50 and 110 and above 110?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to MSE.

You should use the fact that for every event $A$, the complementary event $A^C$ has probability $$\mathbb{P}(A^C)=1-\mathbb{P}(A) . $$

Noting that "price below 50" is the complementary of "price above 50", we get
$$\mathbb{P}(\textrm{"price below 50"}) = 1-\mathbb{P}(\textrm{"price above 50\"}) = 1-0.4 = 0.6 $$

In the same way, since "prince above 110" is the complementary of "price below 110", we have
$$\mathbb{P}(\textrm{"price above 110"}) = 1-\mathbb{P}(\textrm{"price below 110"}) = 1-0.8 = 0.2 $$

Finally, the probability of all space must be 1, so
$$ \mathbb{P}(\textrm{"price below 50"})+\mathbb{P}(\textrm{"price between 50 and 110"})+\mathbb{P}(\textrm{"price above 110"}) = 1 ,$$
and we can calculate
$$ 
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{P}(\textrm{"price between 50 and 110"}) &= 1 - \mathbb{P}(\textrm{"price below 50"}) - \mathbb{P}(\textrm{"price above 110"}) \\
&= 1 - 0.6 - 0.2 = 0.2 . 
\end{aligned}$$